# Is there any way to transfer a SQLite database file from an app to a PC from inside of the app?

Tags: java, android

I have an app that stores info in a table to eventually to be transferred to a PC. However, I can't find any reliable info on how to transfer a db file from a phone to a PC.

Answer (score 0):

just add this permission to manifest :

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

and backup your database like this :

```
public void copyFile()
{
    try 
    {
        File sd = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
        File data = Environment.getDataDirectory();

        if (sd.canWrite()) 
        {
            String currentDBPath = "\\data\\your.package.name\\databases\\dabase_name"; /* REMEMBER TO CHANGE THIS */
            String backupDBPath = "database_name";
            File currentDB = new File(data, currentDBPath);
            File backupDB = new File(sd, backupDBPath);

            if (currentDB.exists()) {
                FileChannel src = new FileInputStream(currentDB).getChannel();
                FileChannel dst = new FileOutputStream(backupDB).getChannel();
                dst.transferFrom(src, 0, src.size());
                src.close();
                dst.close();
            }
            if(bool == true)
            {
                Toast.makeText(Settings.this, "Backup Complete", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                bool = false;
            }
        }               
    } 
    catch (Exception e) {
        Log.w("Settings Backup", e);
    }
}
```

now you can transfer it(from storage) manually to pc or upload to server

Comment: But what happens if there is no SD card to write to?

Comment: it's just a name and it's use internal storage instead